# Why am I getting this Facebook Passport oauth2 response error?

Tags: node.js, facebook

I am trying to integrate Facebook Login to my app using passport (node js). I am seeing my app when redirected to facebook, and i can accept, and upon redirection, i get this error: The code passed is incorrect or expired.

My code is:

```
        passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
                clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID || '',
                clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET || '',
                callbackURL: hostUrl + "/api/auth/facebook/callback"
            },
            async function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
               console.log(profile);
            }
        ));

// PassportService.ts
    public static redirectToHomepage(req: Request, res: Response) {
        if (req.user) {
            const user: any = req.user;
            const token = jwt.sign({userId: user.id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET || 'abc');
            res.redirect('/?token='+token);
        }

    }

    public static authenticateFacebook(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        passport.authenticate('facebook')(req, res, next);
    }

    public static authenticateFacebookCallback(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/auth/login' })(req, res, next);
    }

//routes.ts. endpoint: /api/auth
router.get('/facebook', PassportService.authenticateFacebook);
router.get('/facebook/callback', PassportService.authenticateGithubCallback, PassportService.redirectToHomepage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I see the problem. my route `/facebook/callback` was calling the `PassportService.authenticateGithubCallback`. I changed it to Facebook Callback and now it works.